# How to get last insert id from mysql database in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, sql

I want to get last insert id from my table cart in my else statement after the insert. But I am not getting the id.
Please check my code and suggest what am I doing wrong:

```
// Check to see if the cart COOKIE exists
if ($cart_id != '') {
// Here I want to update but not getting $cart_id, so everytime insert query fire in else statement

}else{

$items_json = json_encode($item);
$cart_expire = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("+30 days"));
$db->query("INSERT INTO cart (items,expire_date) VALUES ('{$items_json}','{$cart_expire}') ");
$cart_id = $db->insert_id; // Here is the problem
setcookie(CART_COOKIE,$cart_id,CART_COOKIE_EXPIRE,'/',$domain,false);
}
```

Your suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: Is `insert_id` auto incremental?

Comment: It is mysqli? ($db) ?

Comment: $cart_id = select @@identity; can I use it like this?

Comment: I am doing this in localhost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO cart (items,expire_date) VALUES ('{$items_json}','{$cart_expire}') ");
$cart_id = $db->insert_id; // Here is the problem
```

Use this, directly from the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO cart (items,expire_date) VALUES ('{$items_json}','{$cart_expire}') ";
mysqli_query($db, $query);
$cart_id = mysqli_insert_id($db);
```

Comment: how to put last insert id in my $cart_id? Like lastInsertId is 71 then $cart_id =71;

Comment: @Sarah updated code, just use `$cart_id = mysqli_insert_id($db);`

Comment: $db->query("INSERT INTO cart (items,expire_date) VALUES ('{$items_json}','{$cart_expire}') ");mysqli_query($db, $query);
  $cart_id = mysqli_insert_id($db);    not working.

Comment: @Sarah you're not using the code I posted. Replace the first 2 lines in my answer in your original code with the second block with 3 lines. You're still using `$db->query` from your original code which is not in my answer.

Comment: Yes the code is working now but still the else statement works I dont know how else statement is working if $cart_id =78; now and not empty.

Answer (score 0):

Get the identity column value AFTER the insert:

```
create table student (
  id int primary key not null auto_increment,
  name varchar(20)
);

insert into student (name) values ('John');

select @@identity; -- returns 1

insert into student (name) values ('Peter');

select @@identity; -- returns 2
```

Comment: I am not getting select @@identity how to use it and how to get last id?

Comment: It's a second query right after the insert in the same session.

Comment: `@@identity` looks like it's more a  SQL server (MSSQL) variable

Comment: Nope, just tested it in MySQL 5.5

Comment: $cart_id = select @@identity; can I use it like this? How to put the value select identity to $cart_id?

Comment: "Nope, just tested it in MySQL 5.5" indeed it's indeed documentated in MySQL 5.5 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_identity .. Seams it was in MySQL already from MySQL 4.1 http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/doc/refman/4.1/en/server-session-variables.html#sysvar_identity  never have known this i assumed `@@identity` was a SQL server (MSSQL) variable

Comment: Wow, didn't know it went that far back (2004?). The oldest MySQL I have worked with is 5.1. Cool.

Answer (score 0):

Or get the next auto incremental value before insert:

```
$query = $db->query("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'cart'");
$next = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $next['Auto_increment'];
```